# Can I play Zelda Ocarina of time for the 3DS on public transport?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, zelda-ocarina-of-time

I have a 3ds and I'm quite interested in getting Zelda for it.

However most of my gaming time at the moment is on my commute to and from work. I have read that the targeting in Zelda uses the gyroscopes and can imagine that this will involve swinging the 3ds wildly around. This could either make me look stupid or cause me to end up hitting a fellow commuter with my prized 3ds.

How much wild flailing does the targeting entail? Is there a non gyroscopic targeting method which can be used instead? Is it possible at all to play this game on public transport?

Comment: "Wild flailing" and "targetting" sound like they're mutually exclusive actions. At least, if you want the latter to be effective in combat.

Comment: It was hard enough to play a NORMAL DS on public transport...The World Ends With You and I didn't get along too nice until we hit the station platform.

Comment: @Shinrai - As long as I was able to sit down, I had no problem playing TWEWY on the bus.

Comment: @KatieK - Buses, I could see.  Subway trains were a problem. >.<

Comment: I was imagining that it could end up like face raiders which wouldn't work on the train.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Gyro aiming is optional and can be turned off if you see fit. As an alternative you can simply use the analogue stick to aim which ever weapon you might be wielding (Its used to aim the slingshot, bow, boom-a-rang, hookshot, etc).

However; as a personal preference I find the gyro-aiming considerably easier and much more responsive to use compared to the stick aiming.

Comment: That's great, all I needed to know.

Comment: When you're on anything that moves - in particular turns - you probably want to turn it off to avoid having your well lined up shot miss because the bus/train/etc made a turn. I prefer to do the rough adjust with the pad and the fine adjust with the gyro - unless I'm on something that moves.